# не могу выбрать правильную кодировку при отправке HttpPost java

Tags: java, кириллица, httpclient, http-post

подскажите пожалуйста что я делаю не так при отправке запроса к серверу?

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(postUrl);
httppost.addHeader("Content-Type","application/json;charset=UTF-8")
StringEntity body = new StringEntity(hashMap.get("JSON").toString());
body.setContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");
httppost.setEntity(body);
```

а сервер кириллицу распознает как "?????"

Comment: вы об этом? postUrl = "http://cityonline.com.ua/bid/add"

Comment: StringEntity body = new StringEntity(hashMap.get("JSON").toString(), ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON.withCharset("UTF-8"));

Comment: мой StringEntity не пропускает Ваш вариант конструктора он требует или StringEntity(String s, String charset) или  StringEntity(String s)

За то пропустил этот: StringEntity body = new StringEntity(hashMap.get("JSON").toString(),"UTF-8"); и на сервер отправилась нужная кодировка